Serre's Representation Theory exercise 7.3(d)
I am trying to solve Exercise 7.3(d) in Serre's Linear Representation of Finite Groups. I have solved all other parts. The important points of where I am stuck at boils down to the following facts. (I have attached pictures of the exercises for further details, if needed.)

Let $H$ be a Frobenius subgroup of $G$ (see details below).
Let $N$ be the set of elements of $G$ which are not conjugate to any element of $H$.
$\chi$ is the character of the permutation representation of $G$ acting on $G/H$. I have shown that $\chi(g)=1$ for $g \notin N$ and $\chi(g)=0$ for $g \in N$ (using the Frobenius subgroup condition). Let $\psi=\chi-1$; $\psi(g)=0$ for $g \notin N$ and $\psi(g)=-1$ for $g \in N$.
Let $f$ be a class function defined on $H$. $\tilde{f}$ extends $f$ to $G$; $\tilde{f}=Ind^G_H f - f(1)\psi$. Note that $\tilde{f}(g) = f(1)$ for $g \in N$. (See 7.3(b,c) for details.)

Exercise 7.3(d) asks to show that $\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle_H = \langle \tilde{f}_1, \tilde{f}_2 \rangle_G$. (Note that $\langle f_1, f_2 \rangle_G := \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} f_1(g^{-1})f_2(g).$)
I have tried to use Frobenius reciprocity, but I am not able to prove the result. (I was able to prove the result using direct computation, so the question must be correct.)
Here is my work:
$$ 
 \langle \tilde{f}_1, \tilde{f}_2 \rangle_G = \langle Ind^G_H f_1-f_1(1)\psi, \tilde{f}_2 \rangle_G= \langle f_1,Res^G_H \tilde{f}_2 \rangle_H - f_1(1) \langle \psi,\tilde{f}_2\rangle_G=\langle f_1,f_2 \rangle_H - f_1(1) \langle \psi,\tilde{f}_2\rangle_G
$$
But $\langle \psi,\tilde{f}_2\rangle_G$ is not zero as needed.
$$\langle \psi,\tilde{f}_2\rangle_G = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in G} \psi(g^{-1}) \tilde{f}_2(g) = \frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in N}\psi(g^{-1}) \tilde{f}_2(g)=\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g \in N} (-1)f_2(1)= -\frac{|N|}{|G|}f_2(1)$$.
Where am I going wrong?
The problem statements are attached below. Exercise 7.2 is used to define $\psi$.




Hint: $f$ is the same as restricting $\tilde{f}$.

@SteveD I have already used that fact ($Res^G_H \tilde{f}_2 = f_2$). I don't see how it helps resolves the contradiction I've encountered ($\langle \psi , \tilde{f}_2 \rangle$ is apparently not zero). Or have I entirely missed the point?

Starting with $\langle \psi,\tilde{f}_2\rangle_G$, use the formula for $\psi$ and Frobenius reciprocity. Now use the formula for $\tilde{f}_2$ given in part (c), and again Frobenius reciprocity. Some things cancel; what are you left with?

Aha! I got it. By repeatedly using the formulae for $\tilde{f}_2$ and $\psi$, I was able to show that $\langle  \psi,\tilde{f}_2\rangle_G=0$. My confusion arose because I computed $\chi$ and, therefore, $\psi$ incorrectly. The correct value is $\psi(e)=|G/H|-1, \psi(g)=0$ for $g \in G-N-{e}$, and $\psi(g)=-1$ for $g \in N$. Thank you very much! Stackexchange and its participants are a boon for self-studying.
